# How to sort ant table column by date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I would like to sort [antd table](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-head) by a `Date` column.

Trying to sort like `sorter: (a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b)`

What I've been doing so far [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-cookies-oejjl) and failed to solve it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this one. This will automatically sort by date ASC to DESC, DESC to ASC as you click the column header. You need to install [moment](https://momentjs.com/)

imports:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Sorter:

```
sorter: (a, b) => moment(a.date).unix() - moment(b.date).unix()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps and more appropriate for me.

Answer (score 18):

`a`,`b` are table records, so you need `new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)`:

```js
{
  title: 'Date',
  dataIndex: 'date',
  key: 'date',
  sorter: (a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)
}
```

[image: Edit Q-56623185-SO-sort by date]

Comment: Thanks @dennis-vash 
This solution is more accurate for me because my data contains some null values for some rows. So sorting working fine for me now with the above method.

Answer (score 3):

{

title: 'Date',

dataIndex: 'date',

key: 'date',

//if you want to compare dates with in hours or minutes or seconds difference

sorter: (a, b) => new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime()
}

Answer (score 0):

check date format "DD-MM-YYYY" REPLACE FORMAT IN SORTER ACCORDING TO YOURS

```
  {title: "Date",
  dataIndex: "Date",
  sorter: {
    compare: (a, b) =>
      moment(a.Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") - moment(b.Date, "DD-MM-YYYY"),
  },}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on what I have seen and it works for me this is my solution :

```
  sorter: {
    compare: (a, b) => {
      a = a.created_date.toLowerCase()
      b = b.created_date.toLowerCase()
      return a > b ? -1 : b > a ? 1 : 0
    },
  },
```

but it would be better if you could do it sorting from backend API instead of just handle it in Front side.

I hope my solution will be useful